# Changing the color of the title in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, axis-labels

I have been working with this for some time and can't find any reasonable explanation for why the names of my x and y axis are the correct color, but not the title.

```
p <- ggplot(movies, aes(x=budget, y=rating))+
  geom_point(shape=1) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "#7F3D17"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "#7F3D17"),
        axis.title = element_text(colour = "#7F3D17"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill='#FFD197'),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank()) +
  labs(x="Budget (in millions)", y="Rating", title="Scatterplot of budget vs movies")
p
```

The scatterplot looks like this (notice that the title is still black):

[image]

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `axis.title = element_text(colour = "#7F3D17")` to get the right color for the title. But you should be using `plot.title = element_text(colour = "#7F3D17")`.

With `axis.title` you define the setting for both axis, whereas with `axis.title.x` or `axis.title.y` you define the setting for the *x-axis title* or *y-axis title* specifically.

Because you are using the same color for all the titles, you can also use `title = element_text(colour = "#7F3D17")` which should set the color of the *plot title*, *axis titles* and *legend title* to the same color.