# Is there a way to change color of title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot and I was wondering if there was a way to change the color of the words in the title. This is the code that I am currently using and I am trying to change the title from black to red.

```r
q <- ggplot(data = graph_data, aes(x = Year_NA)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = MTCT_rate_at_before_birth_mean,color = "blue"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Postnatal_MTCT_rate_to_18_months_from_HIV_diagnosed_mothers_mean,color = "orange"))+
  labs(title= "MTCT rate postnatal vs. prenatal Vs. Year",  
       y="MTCT Rate", x= "Year") +
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "", labels = c("MTC before birth", "MTCT after birth")) +
  theme_bw()
show(q)
```

Comment: You might find this useful: [Changing the color of the title in a ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588909/changing-the-color-of-the-title-in-a-ggplot)

Comment: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() + labs(title = "MTCARS!") + theme(title = element_text(color = "red"))`